# Preimage of singular points of smooth map between manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, singularity-theory, morse-theory

Given a smooth ($C^{\infty}$) map $\phi: V \rightarrow SU(n)$ where $V$ is a (finite dim, real) vector space (of potentially very large dimension) and $SU(n)$ is the special unitary Lie group, what can be said about the  of singularities of this map?

It is know that the preimage $\phi^{-1}(v)$ of a regular value $v$ is a submanifold of $V$. What is known about the preimage of a singular value? Is this also a manifold in this case? What about the preimage of all singular points?

Do the singular values form a manifold? I known they are a null set by Sard's theorem but this does not use anything specific to $SU(n)$. Does the target space being $SU(n)$ help us to say anything more about the singular points?

If we further know that the map $\phi$ is onto does this affect things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the target space being $SU(n)$ gives you much information:

Preimages of singular values can be extremely nasty. Any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of singular points of a function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Embedding $\mathbb{R}$ into $SU(n)$ gives you nasty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. This idea generalizes to higher dimensional vector spaces (although I don't believe any closed subset is the critical set of a smooth function).

Consider the function $e^{1/x} \sin(1/x)$. The critical values are a null set (by sard), but do have an accumulation point $0$, so they do not form a manifold.

More information about $\phi$ will of course give you more information about the critical set: e.g. if $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Morse, we know the that the critical set is discrete, and we have a nice local model of the function around its critical points.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. What would it mean for my map to be Morse? My map is a map between manifolds, not a real valued scalar field on a manifold. Does the concept of a Morse function generalize?

Comment: Well, not directly. I just wanted to state that even in the simplest situation things get extremely complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Just a partial answer.

> It is know that the preimage $ϕ^{-1}(v)$ of a regular value v is a submanifold of V. What is known about the preimage of a singular value? Is this also a manifold in this case?

There is [Transversality theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversality_theorem), which is generalisation of known fact about regular values that you mentioned. Narasimhan in his book "Analysis on real and complex manifolds" states it in following manner:
[image]
where trasversal means:
[image]
This theorem puts additional condtions on $\phi,$ but I believe still it is a good one.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am also aware of the "parametric transversality theorem" which is even stronger and says, very approximately, that if $\phi_s$ is a parameterised family of maps and $\phi$ is transverse for one specific value of $s$ then it is for almost all values of $s$. This theorem requires that the set from which the parameter $s$ is drawn is connected.

Comment: This all being said. We don't yet know that the singular values are a manifold or even an algebraic variety in the first place as far as I can tell.